# snap svg : change viewBox using parameters

Tags: svg, snap.svg

what is the correct syntax to supply a viewBox attribute of an svg element using pre-defined values? I have this :

```
  var mySvg=Snap("#mySvg");
  var worldMap=mySvg.select("#worldMap");//worldMap is an svg inside svg
```

when i tried this :

```
  worldMap.attr({viewBox:"760, 455, 132, 78"});
```

it works just fine. However when i tried it using parameters :

```
var x=760;
var y=455;
var wi=132;
var hi=78;

worldMap.attr({viewBox:"x, y, wi, hi");
```

nothing happened, why? I belive the problem is to find the correct syntax. I also tried :

```
worldMap.attr({viewBox:x, y, wi, hi);
worldMap.attr({viewBox:{x, y, wi, hi});
worldMap.attr({viewBox:(x, y, wi, hi));
worldMap.attr({viewBox:[x, y, wi, hi]);
```

nothing works so far...any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

concatenate your values and your seperators (,) as a string. Try this, it should be working.

```
worldMap.attr({viewBox:x+","+y+","+wi+","+hi});
```

Comment: Never think of that, thank you Holger, it's been helpful.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use:

```
worldMap.attr({viewBox:[x,y,wi,hi].join(',')});
worldMap.attr({viewBox:[x,y,wi,hi].join(' ')});
```

it's more readable

Edit: 
in my first answer i used joining with ',', but in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions) tutorial definition is with space char ' '